# Get access token to local html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

```
$.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function(){

    FB.init({
          appId  : 'my app id',           
          status : true, // check login status
          cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
          xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
    });

});
```

This results in an error: `One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

My goal is to generate an access token on my local html file. My app settings on facebook wont allow "localhost" or anything simiilar.

Is this possible at all, or do I need a local web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research and I would say that this is the easiest way:

```
$.ajax({

url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APPID>&client_secret=<APP SECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials',
dataType: 'text',
success: function(tokenstring){

    var token = tokenstring.split('=')[1];

}

});
```